# Find all lines with a length greater than N

Tags: regex, powershell

This is my first question here. I am just beginning with Powershell.

Let's say I have a text file and I want to match only the lines with a length greater than 10 characters. So I made a really simple regex.

```
$reg = "^\w{0,10}$"
```

And I use the notmatch operator.

```
$myTextFile | Select-String -NotMatch $reg
```

This is not working. I also tried

```
$reg = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,10}$"
```

but this is not working either.

Any clue for me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: "Superior" is not a commonly used word when discussing string length. Do you mean "greater than" or "greater than or equal to"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a regex match. Just do this:

```
Get-Content $myTextFile | ?{$_.Length -gt 10}
```

If you want to do it with a regex, the dot matches any character. This will work...

```
Get-Content $myTextFile | Select-String -NotMatch '^.{0,10}$'
```

...but this is simpler:

```
Get-Content $myTextFile | Select-String '.{11,}'
```

Comment: Note that `.` will match all characters except linefeed (`\`n`), while `\w` will match only alphanumeric characters and underscores. If the OP is just looking at the length of the string, I'd recommend using your first example. If he's looking for strings starting with more than 10 consecutive alphanumeric characters he'll have to go with something like `^\w{11,}`.